# Set value of a key in an array of objects in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way in ES6, to set value of a key in all objects, in an array of objects to a new value.

```
[
    {title: 'my title', published: false},
    {title: 'news', published: true}, 
    ...
]
```

For example, setting every item `published` value to `true`?

Comment: I think you need to loop or use one of the array methods

Comment: Can you share an example of **multi-dimensional** array and expected output?

Comment: One way or another, your code has to iterate. That can be either explicit `for` loops or via the Array prototype iteration methods.

Comment: you want to get an array like `[['my Title', false], ['news', true]]`?

Comment: What @gurvinder372 is trying to tell you is that your example is an object array and not a multidimentional one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array in your example is just a one-dimensional array of objects.

You can do what you asked with `forEach` and a lambda:

`array.forEach(element => element.published = true);`

Comment: @vahdet the terminology in the question is wrong. It is actually an array of objects.

Comment: Ah okay. Just looked at the score and could not think that he would not state it that basically wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`

```
arr = arr.map( s => (s.published = true, s) );
```

**Edit**

No need to set the return value either, just

```
arr.map( s => (s.published = true, s) );
```

would suffice

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
    title: 'my title',
    published: false
  },
  {
    title: 'news',
    published: true
  }
];
arr.map(s => (s.published = true, s));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Your `map` is modifying the array. The concept of `map` is that it returns a new array of new instances, with old data unmodified.

Comment: Marko you can still see when and where the array got it's values redefined as opposite to `forEach` which can produce unexpected side-effects.

Comment: @MarkoBjelac `map` returns an array and I am setting the returned value to the same array (though not required).

Comment: @Roland - please explain - how can you see where you used `map` and not `forEach`? What are these unexpected side-effects of `forEach` and how are they different when you're modifying the array in the `map`?

Comment: @gurvinder372 - "though not required" is true, but I would much prefer the language to *forbid it*. If a method returns void, I naturally assume its changing the argument. If a method returns the same type as its input, I naturally assume its not touching the input. I know this is far from true in JS, and its annoying as hell. I have to carefully check the documentation of common libraries all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a loop.

`arr` represents your array of objects

```
var result = []
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  result.push([arr[i].title, arr[i].published])
}
console.log(result)
```

this will result in `[['my Title', false], ['news', true]]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a loop you can refer with index.

```
    a = [
        {title: 'my title', published: false},
        {title: 'news', published: true}
        ]

a[0].published= true;
a[1].published= true;
```

or loop it

```
        for (val in a) {
            a[val].published = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` function with spread operator

`let array = [
  { title: 'my title', published: false },
  { title: 'news', published: true }
]`

`array = array.map(t => t.published !== true ? { ...t, published: true } : t)`